# Why is there a difference in formatting a DateTime depending on the incoming DateTime-Format?

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting

I have code which parses a DateTime and formats it like this:

```
DateTime.Parse(DateTimeValueXY, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
```

In one case I get the error

> *String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.*

The confusing thing for me is the following:

When the DateTime which needs to be formatted has this format "**MM/dd/yyyy**" the formating works:

```
// WORKS
DateTime.Parse("10/19/2022", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
```

But if the DateTime has already the correct format the mentioned error is thrown:

```
// Error -> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime
DateTime.Parse("19/10/2022", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
```

So there are two questions:

- Why this throws the error if the format is already correct?
- How would one handle the fact that the DateTime which needs to be formatted can have both formats?

Comment: Repeat after me: a `DateTime` object has no format, it's just a 64-bit number.

Comment: `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is basically US format, so your datetime string would have to be in MM/dd/yyyy format to parse successfully.

Comment: OK, let's ask a different question: what date is 05/03/2022? Is that May 3rd, or the 5th of March? According to the code you have, it's May 3rd. As there aren't 19 months, 19/10/2022 can't parse successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateTime.Parse` is failing not the `ToString()` because the input format is not correct.

You need to use `DateTime.ParseExact` and provide the correct format string or use a valid format (e.g. UK format) with `DateTime.Parse`:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("19/10/2022", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

OR

```
DateTime.Parse("19/10/2022", new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

In response to the second part of your question ***"How would one handle the fact that the DateTime which needs to be formatted can have both formats?"***, you should provide the format that the date is supposed to have by using either of the above methods.

Comment: Thx for the clarification. Yes, best would be to ensure that the relevant DateTIme is already stored in the appropriate format